# ¿Cómo hago para que la musica en una web no se cierre al cambiar de pagina?

Tags: html

tengo este codigo en la pagina index.html

```html
<audio controls>
        <source src="Fondo-Flamenco-ChillOut-Beautiful-Spanish-Guitar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf?Fondo-Flamenco-ChillOut-Beautiful-Spanish-Guitar.mp3">
            <param name="movie" value="player.swf?Fondo-Flamenco-ChillOut-Beautiful-Spanish-Guitar.mp3">
            </object>
    </audio>
```

pero al cambiar de pagina, se cierra el reproductor, como lo hago para que la musica se mantenga mientras navego por cualquier pagina del site? Gracias!!

Comment: Hola Basic. Es una pregunta muy amplia ya que no sabemos como tienes montada la pagina. Además, todo lo que digamos van a ser sugerencias lo cual es basado en opiniones y motivo de cierre. Has de investigar e intentarlo. Si tienes errores o problemas, preguntar aqui siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Si quieres orientacion, puedes pregutnar en el [chat] . Un saludo

Comment: Respuesta breve: Si cambias la página y tu aplicación no es una SPA (webs de página unica) , el HTML actual se elimina para carga la nueva página, con lo que no es posible mantener la música.

Comment: hola Pablo, que es una SPA? y si al clicar se abriera en un pop-up aparte para que no se cerrara?

Comment: Voy a dejar aquí mi humilde respuesta ya que no estoy 100% seguro de lo que diré a continuación. Has pensado en la página como iframe, así estas siempre en la misma página principal, ya que solo cambiara el contenido y la música no se cortará.

Comment: Hola Calderio, he probado a poner un iframe en varias paginas pero al cambiar de una a otra se corta la musica.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tener (únicamente) el reproductor en tu página index.html y hacer que ésta sea un 'contenedor' para el resto de páginas. Así no te saldrías nunca de index y mantendrías el reproductor. Puedes hacerlo añadiendo el reproductor y un `<iframe>` en el index.html.

Prueba a crear estos ficheros en local para que se entienda mejor el concepto:

**Fichero: index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Reproductor</div>
  <iframe src="principal.html" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Fichero: principal.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Página principal</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Fichero: contacto.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #FDE8F2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Página de contacto</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <a href="principal.html">volver</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora abre/carga index.html y prueba a navegar entre principal y contacto. Como puedes ver, mantienes arriba el "reproductor"

Comment: El reproductor de música iría en index.html. Es la página que contiene a todas las demás (principal, contacto, ...) La "principal" sería la tu 'anterior' index.html. Lo que ven las personas sin haber entrado en ningún sitio.

Comment: entiendo que lo que dices es que este todo el tiempo en la pag index y las otras se veran a traves de un iframe de la index

Comment: Te recomiendo copiar ese código y crear cada uno de los tres ficheros en tu PC. Después cargas el index.html. Así se verá más claro

Comment: Correcto, el index.html siempre se mantiene y solo varía el contenido de dentro a través del iframe. El index es el que tendrá el reproductor.

Comment: esta genial, a ver si me sale...

Comment: el problema es que descuenta el espacio del <header> y el del <footer> y me deja un especio muy pequeño para visualizar las páginas a las que les pone un scroll vertical, queda fatal

Comment: Si tus páginas tienen un header y un footer, ambos serían candidatos para estar en la página 'principal' en lugar de en cada una. Por defecto el iframe ocupa un tamaño fijo (y reducido), pero puedes cambiarlo para que ocupe el 100% de la página. Si te fijas, mi ejemplo lo hace así. Te recomiento que te copies y crees los 3 ficheros y veamos como funciona. Quedará mucho más claro!

Comment: hola Julio! la pag index.html la he dejado solo con el reproductor. el header y footer ya lo llevan el resto de pags. y muestra las paginas en un espacio muy reducido con scroll y el resto la pag la deja en blanco,aun peor

Comment: Hay alguna manera de que podamos verlo en funcionamiento?

Comment: Hola Julio! si que funciona tal cual pero no puede llevar el menu, solo el reproductor en una franja arriba, el resto es <iframe> y el menu, footer y demas lo lleva cada pagina. Pero sale una barra de scroll vertical, ahora estoy averiguando como quitarla. Saludos!